# Creating Gradle modules that can talk to each other

Tags: java, gradle

This is my project structure:

```
Parent
---- build.gradle
---- settings.gradle
-------- Server
------------ src\main\Server.java
------------ src\test\ServerTest.java
------------ build.gradle
-------- Game
------------ src\main\Game.java
------------ src\test\GameTest.java
------------ build.gradle
```

What I am trying to do is setup the my Gradle project so that Server can talk to Game and Game can talk to server.

How can I setup my Gradle project to allow me to do this?

Comment: What do mean by "talk to" ?

Comment: @Hedge7707 -  Message passing, so the Server can send Game messages that it can respond to and the Game can send the Server a reply. I tried creating some sort of Bus but I can't seem to share an instance of an object between the two modules (they don't see it).

Comment: So are Game and Server local to the same machine ... Why are you trying communicate over some sort of Bus as opposed to through a socket?

Comment: @Hedge7707 There is a client separate from this project that the server communicates over a socket with.

Comment: What does this have to do with Gradle? Its job is to build your software. Communication between your two applications happens after they're built and running.

Comment: Do you get any sort of error in the build?

Comment: @PeterLedbrook  Hi, from what I was told I can use gradle to make modules interact with each other (ie. one module can see classes etc of another) - is this possible to do? Currently Server cannot see anything that Game has.

Comment: Do you have dependencies { } closures in your build.gradle files?